# Changing the way your mobile displays incoming calls - Where to begin?

Tags: mobile, java-me, mobile-phones, real-time

Here's a situation: I own a nokia mobile device. Quite often, I receive calls from unknown local/national numbers. Now, I would like to take those calls that are from unknown national numbers coz they could be important and I would not like to take calls from local numbers. I would like to write an application which displays "  calling" instead of the regular "  calling". For instance, " AT&T, CA". I have a database of codes with carriers and their reserved numbers for each state.

Now, I know this not simple coz I am talking about changing something that is native to the mobile phone. Sure, I could write a java app or a symbian app or something like that, but obviously, that would be kind of an aftermath app, which you would run after you've missed the call. I need something that is real-time.

So, to do what I want, where do I start? Is it even possible? Does some sort of SDK exist for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Without known the specific type of the phone I can only give you a general answer.

You have to find out if the APIs that your phone supports (J2ME or symbian) support an event to watch for incomming calls.

Then it should be simple.

Comment: Nokia 3G 2730 - that's my nokia device. I do own a Sony ericsson - C902, too.